# Sending direct_message with twitteroauth

Tags: message, twitter-oauth

I get a strange error and couldn't find the answer..
This code works well:

```
$receiverScrName='name';

$method = 'direct_messages/new';
$parameters = array('screen_name' => $receiverScrName, 'text' => 'how are you');
$dm = $oauth->post($method, $parameters);
```

This code below doesn't work. Only change is "$message" parameter.

```
$receiverScrName='name';
$message='Hello man';   

$method = 'direct_messages/new';
$parameters = array('screen_name' => $receiverScrName, 'text' => $message);
$dm = $oauth->post($method, $parameters);
```

It gives error:

```
stdClass Object ( [error] => Could not authenticate with OAuth.
                 [request] => /1/direct_messages/new.json )
```

---

I tried to encode "message" :

```
 $message='Hello man';
 $message=urlencode($message);

 $method = 'direct_messages/new';
 $parameters = array('screen_name' => $receiverScrName, 'text' => $message );
 $dm = $oauth->post($method, $parameters);
```

The message is sent.
But the received message became "Hello+man".

How can i remove "plus" or other escaped characters from the message that will be sended?
Thank you

Comment: I am unable to reproduce the version with `$message` not working. Maybe you just had a random error from Twitter?

Comment: Soon i found out that this is related with non-ASCII characters in "$message". It is working when i transliterate that characters. But if an UTF-8 only character exist in message text, this doesn't work. I suppose also twitter transliterates non-ASCII characters when i send direct messages by using twitter.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that this problem is related with non-ASCII characters in message text.
When i transliterate them it is worked.